# Optimized ListView with pre-calculated element size

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, optimization

I need to display a very large collection of elements (images from files) in a `ListView`, using the usual `ListView.builder` constructor. I statically know the size of each element so, technically, I know also the total height of the list view.
The problem is that I need to programmatically scroll up or down in a position of the list, using a `ScrollController` associated to the list.
Using the `ScrollController`, I know how to scroll the list to the correct position, but I think that this is not performed efficiently.

In iOS, the same scenario can be resolved using a `TableView`, and it is possible to instruct the underlining framework about the correct size of each element, without the necessity to pre-build each element to know the correct size (that is what Flutter should perform in order to scroll up or down the list).

For my knowledge, it is not possible to instruct Flutter about the size of each list element, but I think that this information could be extremely useful to create a more optimized list view, at least in this particular case.

Do you know about any library or other possibility to improve this logic?

EDIT: more specifically, I want to know if there is a way to optimize the list view, telling Flutter the size of each element of the list, without any calculation based on the list element.

SOLUTION:
I discovered that the ListView.builder as an additional (and optional) parameter, named prototypeItem, that allows to predefined the prototype of the list element, and use it for the calculation of scroll and so on.

In my test, using this parameter dramatically improve the performance of the ListView.